# How do I remove a Google Account from my phone?

Tags: sync, samsung-galaxy-s-5, active-sync

My gal pal used my Galaxy S5 to sign into her Gmail.  She Added "another account' to my g-mail but could not find a way to sign out when done. Now, all of her mail and calendar stuff is showing up on my phone!  Help me stop this!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way how.

1. Go into the GMail App
2. Select the menu button(top left of the screen next to "Inbox"
3. Click the down arrow next to your email
4. Select manage accounts.
5. It will take you to another menu, select "Google"
6. Find her account, click on it, and in the top right corner of the screen there should be 3 dots you can push to bring down a menu, and select remove account.

Comment: Can also remove the account in your phone's settings menu. Scroll down til you see accounts.